# $N$ identical Balls to be placed in $P$ non-identical boxes with maximum $K$ in each box

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can $N$ identical balls be put in $P$ non-identical boxes such that no box is left empty and all boxes contain less than or equal to $K$ balls.

I have worked out the following formula,

$${N-1 \choose P-1} -  P \times\sum_{i = P - 2}^{N - (K + 1)} {i \choose P - 2}$$

Also we have $P =  \lfloor N/K \rfloor + 1 $

Is there any simpler formula, any way to better its computationality?

Comment: There is a simple recurrence thinking about the final box.

Comment: A variation of "stars and bars" where each $x_i$ lies in $[1,K]$ and $1 \le i \le P.$ But not quite stars and bars because of the upper bound on the $x_i.$

Comment: @Henry, I am not able to get that simple recurrence given the upper bound. Could you please explain it more?

Comment: @coffeemath, Yeah that's where I got my formula from. Used the logic of stars and bars.

Comment: Shashank-- stars and bars becomes quite difficult to apply if there are upper bounds on the $x_i.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the the number of ways $f(N,P,K)$.  Then,  thinking about the final box, you have $$f(N,P,K) = \sum_{m=1}^K f(N-m,P-1,K)$$ starting with $f(0,0,K)=1$ and $f(N,0,K)=0$ when $N \not = 0$.  This is related to a generalised form of Pascal's triangle (slightly skewed)

So for example, if $K=3$, you would get a table which starts like this

```
    P   0   1   2   3
N
0       1   0   0   0
1       0   1   0   0
2       0   1   1   0
3       0   1   2   1
4       0   0   3   3
5       0   0   2   6
6       0   0   1   7
7       0   0   0   6
8       0   0   0   3
9       0   0   0   1
```

and these are known as *trinomial coefficients*, with each value the sum of the three values immediately above in the previous column.  With $K=2$ there would be *binomial coefficients*, and with $K=4$ there would be *quadrinomial coefficients*, and so on for larger $K$

Answer (score 0):

You could start by filling all the boxes and count ways to reduce the number of balls according to your rules.

I think the number $n$ of balls to reduce is between $1$ and $P$, and we should stars and bars is over $P$ boxes, with one special case where $n = P$, and we can't have all balls removed from 1 box in any of $P$ ways.